# Django mocking a function in a View does not work

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

Ok so here is the situation.
I'm using Django, DRF and for tests django.test and unitest.mock
I have a View which executes a method inside a post request sending a message to Kafka (`send_message_to_kafka`).
This method is not in a viewset and I am trying to mock it.
I wrote 2 tests.

1. to call a method wrapper_send_message_to_kafka() which calls send_message_to_kafka inside it.
2. self.client.post("/viewset/", data=payload).

Both of these tests mocks the function send_message_to_kafka bypassing the actual publish to Kafka.

```
@mock.patch('utils.send_message_to_kafka', return_value={"success": True, "message": "Message sent to Kafka successfully!"})
```

But the first works as expected and the second is not mocked.

#### View

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def example_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
    ...
       result = send_message_to_kafka(json.dumps((message)))
```

#### Tests

```
from django.test import TestCase
import unittest.mock as mock
...

@mock.patch('utils.pubsub.send_message_to_kafka', return_value={"success": True, "message": "Message sent to Kafka successfully!"})
def test_send_message_to_kafka(self, send_message_mock):
    result = wrapper_send_message_to_kafka()
    self.assertTrue(result["success"])    

@mock.patch('utils.send_message_to_kafka', return_value={"success": True, "message": "Message sent to Kafka successfully!"})
def test_start_run(self, send_message_mock):
    response = self.client.post(
       "/execute/",
       data=payload,
       format="json",
    )
```

Comment: You should be mocking place where mocked object is used, so in your case views.send_message to kafka